# Как проверить принадлежность числа к диапазону?

Tags: php

Предположим, есть рандомный массив чисел

```
$array = [163, 746, 194, 1846, 5684, 933]
```

Как проверить к какому из диапазонов относится каждое число?
Диапазон такой

```
300-600
600-900
900-1200
1200-1500
и тд
Всегда +300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим есть рандомное число (решив задачу для одного числа, решим и для множества) 163. И есть диапазон 300-600. Как же узнать лежит ли число 163 в диапазоне от 300, до 600?

Возможно, если число больше нижней границы диапазона и в тоже самое время меньше верхней, то оно лежит в этом диапазоне!

Если диапазонов несколько, проверку то надо произвести для каждого. Возможно число лежит сразу в нескольких диапазонах! например 600 лежит в диапазоне от 300 до 600 включительно и в диапазоне от 600 до 900 включительно.

Но что если диапазонов нет, а есть только знание о "всегда +300". Можно было бы построить все диапазоны по 300 до PHP_INT_MAX, но это довольно глупо, ведь можно посчитать сколько раз 300 влазит в рандомное число (эта операция называется делением). 
Для большего удобства можно воспользоваться функцией [целочисленного деления](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.intdiv.php).

Попробуем! Набирите в консоли `php -a` и повторяйте за мной:

- `$x = intdiv(163, 300);` (нажмите enter)
- `echo $x;` -- php говорит 0!
- Теперь как из этого нуля получить диапазон? `echo sprintf('%d-%d', $x * 300, ($x + 1) * 300);`

Попробуйте с другими числами, а потом напишите клёвый код.